# li with {display: table-cell; position: relative;} with absolutely positioned div inside behaves differently in (FF4, WebKit) vs (Opera, IE9)

Tags: html, css, css-position

Here is a complete test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>

  <style type="text/css">

    html, body, ul, li, div, span {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul.container {
        display: table;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-right: 24px;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.container li {
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.container div, ul.container span {
        border: 1px dotted #000;
    }

    ul.container div {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40px;
        background-color: #008000;
    }

    ul.container span {
        display: block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #9acd32;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="container">
  <li>
    <span>Alice</span>
    <div>Alice</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Bob</span>
    <div>Bob</div>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Absolutely positioned `div` has `li` as `offsetParent` in IE9 and Opera, while WebKit and Firefox set `offsetParent` to `body`.

*IE9, Opera*

[image: result in IE9 and Opera]

*Firefox 4, WebKit*

[image: result in Firefox 4 and WebKit]

**My question is**: what is the correct behavior?

Comment: This seems to be tabular data. Why not just use a juicy table tag?

Comment: Coincidence. It's not a tabular data ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ul.container div` has `position: absolute;left: 0;` I think that Firefox and Webkit have the correct behavior. I don't know what you need to achieve, if the appearance of IE9 and Opera is the correct then I suggest you to remove `position: absolute;left: 0;`

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6yXwb/

Comment: But shouldn't having `position: relative` on the li make the `position: absolute` on the div act relative to it's relatively positioned parent?

if the display isn't `table-cell`, and you float the `li`s left. then I think you should get the IE9/Opera result. I'm at work & stuck on IE7, but someone else could check this: http://jsfiddle.net/3wRTu/

Comment: PS - I'm not saying you're wrong. I just always thought a `relative` parent always changed the positioning context of an `absolute` child

Comment: Well, `position: relative` on `li` doesn't affect `position: absolute` on `div`. That's strange. I suppose that `display: table-cell` is the culprit. I know, how to achieve the same positioning using floats. This question is just from my curiosity :p

Comment: @Ivan Yatskevich: `display: table-cell` is the culprit. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position - `The effect of 'position:relative' on .. table-cell.. elements is undefined.`

Comment: It seems that the answer of @thirtydot is the correct answer. Thanks! :)